# Dart : How to ignore omit_local_variable_types warning?

Tags: dart, compiler-warnings

I'm developing a mobile app plus web frontend with Dart / Flutter with IntelliJ Idea. The current version of Dart warns about correctly typing local variables. There is a Dart style guide https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/omit_local_variable_types.html saying "Usually, the types of local variables can be easily inferred, so it isn't necessary to annotate them."

This might be true for a compiler but it sure is not true for human readers. Since it especially defers type problems to the usage part of a variable, bug detection and code reading is becoming more expensive.

So how can I disable this warning on compiler / project level?

Even better: how can I force a warning if the type is not set?

Comment: Where did you get that version? Latest stable version of Dart is currently 2.6.1 and the dev version are 2.7.0-dev.2.1: https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive

Comment: Told by Idea -> Settings -> Languages -> Dart
it says: "Version: 2.8.0-edge.413..."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this is a bit old, but I see there isn’t an answer, so adding here now for future use.

In the root of your project folder, add an “analysis_options.yaml” file, and include the below code. Read further at: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

analysis _options.yaml:

```
linter:
    rules:
        always_specify_types: true
        omit_local_variable_types: false
```

Unsure if both are required when always specifying types, but give it a go.

Answer (score 8):

To ignore the warnings only for a specific file:

```dart
// ignore_for_file: omit_local_variable_types

class Foo {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `// ignore: omit_local_variable_types` above warning code line:

```
  // ignore: omit_local_variable_types
  int years = (dif.inDays / 365).floor();
```