# How to disable the warning "Omit type annotations for local variables"? in Dart (with Pedantic Package)

Tags: flutter, dart, linter

I use the pedantic package in Flutter and I have the following `anaylsis_options.yaml` file:

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml # advanced linter

analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - extension-methods

linter:
  rules:
    omit_local_variables_types: false
    # always_specify_types: true
```

I try to disable the "Omit type annotations for local variables" warning. I can only disable it, I uncomment the last line (see question [Dart 2.8.0 sdk: how to globally ignore omit_local_variable_types warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211916/dart-2-8-0-sdk-how-to-globally-ignore-omit-local-variable-types-warning)). But I don't want to specify every type. So that's not what I want.

So how get I disable this warning globally?

Comment: Just a comment, Pedantic Dart is really aimed  at the Google dart / flutter sdk developers. You may be better off using the effective_dart package. I started using pedantic but have switched to effective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a feature that came later than when the question is posted, but according to [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#ignoring-rules) you can ignore rules.

So if  you want to disable warnings for `omit_local_variable_types` rule you can do the following in your `anaylsis_options.yaml` file:

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    omit_local_variable_types: ignore
```