# Dart - assign value only if null (??=) gives warning message

Tags: dart

When I execute this small dart program:

```
void main() {
  int? someint;
  someint ??= 123;
  someint ??= 246;
  print(someint);
}
```

I get the following warning message;

```
$ dart test.dart 
test.dart:4:3: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??=' has type 'int' which excludes null.
  someint ??= 246;
  ^
123
```

So everything works as expected, but the warning message is annoying. Is there any way to suppress this warning message?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a warning because the compiler knows that it is impossible that the assignment will occur as you had just done a nullish assign before. There is a better error message on dart pad:

```dart
void main() {
  int? someint;
  someint ??= 123;
  someint ??= 246; // <- warning here
  print(someint);
}
```

```
line 4 • The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed. (view docs)
Try removing the operator and the right operand.
```

Your code still compiles, although there is no reason why you should do another nullish assign as it would never run.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Have noticed if I replace the second assignment with `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) someint ??= 246;`, then there's no warning. Do you know if there's any way of suppressing such warnings?

Comment: I'd assume the for loop example works because there aren't null assign checks within the first part of the for loop condition for performance reasons. I think you should be able to ignore the lints by following this question's responses https://stackoverflow.com/q/59211916/10873797